# shopware 6 : How to add custom menu in offCanvas menu element?

Tags: javascript, plugins, shopware, off-canvas-menu

I want to add custom menu in offCanvas menu. Here in below image after categpries i want to display my custom menu name=> Profile and also language switcher menu .can anyone help me how to do this?[image]

Comment: There should be a language switcher already if the right conditions are given.
And you need to extend the template for the extra menu.
For example: storefront/layout/navigation/offcanvas/navigation.html.twig